# Custom contact search in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I am very much new in the Android app development. I wrote the code to implement contact list in my android app successfully. If I click on a specific contact it shows me the contact name and contact number/s with contact type(Home, phone, other etc). Now I want to add search functionality in it. but I failed to do so. Following is code:

```
public class Contacts extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "[Contacts]";
    private static final String headerTitle = "Pick a Contact";
    private static final String searchtext = "";
    // Default List view for loading the list
    ListView lstContacts;


    JSONObject o;
    public static boolean goahead = false;

    // Added for fee calculation in background
    public SQLiteDatabase db;

    // Context
    Context context;

    // AndroidConstants declaration
    AndroidConstants ac;

    // Declarations for the Contact list
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
    MatrixCursor mMatrixCursor;
    TextView tv_name;
    TextView tv_details;
    public static String details_comm;
    EditText inputSearch;
    // ProgressBar pbHeaderProgress;
    LinearLayout progressBarLayout;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    // onCreate event
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);
        progressBarLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linlaHeaderProgress);
        progressBarLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar = ActionBarHelper
                .customActionBar(actionBar, headerTitle, "1");

        context = getApplicationContext();
        lstContacts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // The contacts from the contacts content provider is stored in this
        // cursor
        mMatrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { "_id", "name",
                "details" });
        tv_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tv_details = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_details);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        // Adapter to set data in the listview

        // HIDING INPUTSEARCH
        // inputSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                R.layout.lv_layout, null, new String[] { "name", "details" },
                new int[] { R.id.tv_name, R.id.tv_details }, 0);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // Setting the adapter to listview
        lstContacts.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        lstContacts.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        // Creating an AsyncTask object to retrieve and load listview with
        // contacts
        ListViewContactsLoader listViewContactsLoader = new ListViewContactsLoader();

        // Starting the AsyncTask process to retrieve and load listview with
        // contacts
        listViewContactsLoader.execute();

        // Database instance
        db = openOrCreateDatabase(ac.database_name,
                SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        db.setVersion(1);
        db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        db.setLockingEnabled(true);

        // Code for fee calculation working as a background process
        FeeCalculation feeCal = new FeeCalculation();
        feeCal.execute();

        lstContacts.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int position, long index) {

                String tempData = ((TextView) (view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name)))
                        .getText().toString();
                String tempData2 = ((TextView) (view
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_details))).getText().toString();
                String[] data = new String[2];
                data[0] = tempData;
                data[1] = tempData2;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Contacts.this, ProcessContacts.class);
                intent.putExtra("data", data);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_in,
                        R.anim.slide_left_out);
                finish();
            }
        });

        // Code added for contact list search

        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                Log.d(TAG, "search:" + cs.toString());

                if (mAdapter != null) {
                    mAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        mAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                Log.d(TAG, "CharSequence constraint");
                Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
                Log.d(TAG, "CharSequence constraint1");
                String[] projection = new String[] {
                        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, };
                Log.d(TAG, "CharSequence constraint2");
                String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                        + " like '" + constraint.toString() + "%'";
                Log.d(TAG, "CharSequence constraint3");
                String[] selectionArgs = null;
                String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                        + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
                Log.d(TAG, "CharSequence constraint4");
                Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                        selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
                String a = DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cur);
                Log.e("TAG", "String for the filter===>" + a);
                return cur;

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(Contacts.this);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Contacts.this,
                    AcceptAmountActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_right_in,
                    R.anim.slide_right_out);
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /** An AsyncTask class to retrieve and load listview with contacts */

    private class ListViewContactsLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor> {

        protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String displayName = "";
            String homePhone = "";
            String mobilePhone = "";
            String workPhone = "";
            String contact = "";
            Log.d(TAG, "ListViewContactsLoader");
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    null, null, "UPPER("
                            + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
            String phone = "";
            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                    String id = cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name = cur
                            .getString(cur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    if (Integer
                            .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                        System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);
                        Cursor pCur = cr
                                .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                        null,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                                + " = ?", new String[] { id },
                                        null);
                        String details = "";
                        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {

                            phone = pCur.getString(pCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));

                            int type = pCur.getInt(pCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));

                            switch (type) {
                            case Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                                details += "Home:" + phone + ",";
                                break;
                            case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                                details += "Mobile:" + phone + ",";
                                break;
                            case Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                                details += "Work:" + phone + ",";
                                break;
                            case Phone.TYPE_OTHER:
                                details += "Other:" + phone + ",";
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                        name = name.trim();
                        details = details.trim();
                        contact = name + " \n";
                        contact += details;
                        contact = contact.trim();
                        mMatrixCursor
                                .addRow(new Object[] { id, name, details });
                        pCur.close();
                    }
                }
            }
            return mMatrixCursor;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
            mAdapter.swapCursor(result);
            progressBarLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }    
}
```

App gets crashed and gave the following error:
10-28 18:29:22.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26985): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'name' does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did following channges in the code. I use listview adapter instead of cursor adapter and achieve my requirement.

```
public class Contacts extends Activity {    
    private static final String TAG = "[Contacts]";
    private static final String headerTitle = "Pick a Contact";
    private static final String searchtext = "";
    // Default List view for loading the list
    ListView lstContacts;

    // PostTask posttask;
    public static String number, MAC_ID, IMEI, gotArrayString, error_code,
            error_desc;

    // Added for tran no
    public static int count = 0;

    JSONObject o;
    public static boolean goahead = false;

    // Added for fee calculation in background
    public SQLiteDatabase db;

    // Context
    Context context;

    // AndroidConstants declaration
    AndroidConstants ac;

    // Declarations for the Contact list
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
    MatrixCursor mMatrixCursor;
    TextView tv_name;
    TextView tv_details;
    public static String details_comm;
    EditText inputSearch;

    LinearLayout progressBarLayout;

    List<String> nameArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> detailsArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    private SimpleAdapter adapter;

    private ContactGlobalModel cont = new ContactGlobalModel();
    private ArrayList<String> arraynamelist = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> arraydetailslist = new ArrayList<String>();

    //SimpleAdaptor
    private static List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    private static Map<String, String> map;
    private static int countx;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    // onCreate event
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);
        progressBarLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linlaHeaderProgress);
        progressBarLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar = ActionBarHelper
                .customActionBar(actionBar, headerTitle, "1");

        context = getApplicationContext();
        lstContacts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        Intent i = getIntent();

        tv_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tv_details = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_details);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        // Adapter to set data in the listview
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list, R.layout.lv_layout, new String[] { "name", "details" }, new int[] { R.id.tv_name, R.id.tv_details });
        lstContacts.setAdapter(adapter);
        lstContacts.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        lstContacts.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        // Contact list loader cursor
        Cursor curContact;

        // Creating an AsyncTask object to retrieve and load list view with
        // contacts
        ListViewContactsLoader listViewContactsLoader = new ListViewContactsLoader();

        // Starting the AsyncTask process to retrieve and load listview with
        // contacts
        listViewContactsLoader.execute();

        // Database instance
        db = openOrCreateDatabase(ac.DATABASE_NAME,
                SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        db.setVersion(1);
        db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        db.setLockingEnabled(true);

        // Code for fee calculation working as a background process
        FeeCalculation feeCal = new FeeCalculation();
        feeCal.execute();

        lstContacts.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int position, long index) {

                String tempData = ((TextView) (view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name)))
                        .getText().toString();
                String tempData2 = ((TextView) (view
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_details))).getText().toString();
                String[] data = new String[2];
                data[0] = tempData;
                data[1] = tempData2;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Contacts.this, ProcessContacts.class);
                intent.putExtra("data", data);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_in,
                        R.anim.slide_left_out);
                finish();
            }
        });

        // Code added for contact list search

        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Contacts.this,
                    AcceptAmountActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_right_in,
                    R.anim.slide_right_out);
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /** An AsyncTask class to retrieve and load listview with contacts */

    private class ListViewContactsLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor> {

        protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String displayName = "";
            String homePhone = "";
            String mobilePhone = "";
            String workPhone = "";
            String contact = "";
            Log.d(TAG, "ListViewContactsLoader");
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    null, null, "UPPER("
                            + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
            String a = DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cur);
            Log.e("TAG",
                    "String for the filter================================================================>"
                            + a);
            String phone = "";
            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                    String id = cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name = cur
                            .getString(cur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    if (Integer
                            .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                        System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);
                        Cursor pCur = cr
                                .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                        null,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                                + " = ?", new String[] { id },
                                        null);
                        String details = "";
                        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {

                            phone = pCur.getString(pCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));

                            int type = pCur.getInt(pCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));

                            System.out.println("=======>" + "name : " + name
                                    + ", ID : " + id + " Mob : " + phone);

                            switch (type) {
                            case Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                                details += "Home:" + phone + ",";
                                break;
                            case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                                details += "Mobile:" + phone + ",";
                                break;
                            case Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                                details += "Work:" + phone + ",";
                                break;
                            case Phone.TYPE_OTHER:
                                details += "Other:" + phone + ",";
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        name = name.trim();
                        details = details.trim();
                        contact = name + " \n";
                        contact += details;
                        contact = contact.trim();

                        nameArray.add(name);
                        detailsArray.add(details);
                        pCur.close();
                    }
                }
            }

            String[] nameStrArray = new String[nameArray.size()];
            nameArray.toArray(nameStrArray);

            String[] detailsStrArray = new String[detailsArray.size()];
            detailsArray.toArray(detailsStrArray);

            for (int i = 0; i < nameStrArray.length; i++) {
                ContactGlobalModel cm = new ContactGlobalModel(nameStrArray[i],
                        detailsStrArray[i]);
                arraynamelist.add(cm.getName());
                arraydetailslist.add(cm.getDetails());
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "arraynamelist size====>"+arraynamelist.size());
            Log.d(TAG, "arraydetailslist size====>"+arraydetailslist.size());

            countx = arraynamelist.size();
            Log.d(TAG, "Count========>"+String.valueOf(countx));
            list.clear();
            for(int v = 0; v < countx; v++) {
                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("name", arraynamelist.get(v));
                map.put("details", arraydetailslist.get(v));
                list.add(map);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
            // mAdapter.swapCursor(result);

            progressBarLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    // Killing the application
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_right_in, R.anim.slide_right_out);

    }

}
```